# NSZombieEnabled stops app from crashing

Tags: iphone, ios, nszombieenabled

I enabled NSZombieEnabled and my app stopped from crashing. The debugger isn't outputting anything that could help me so this was my only hope. Do you have any suggestions to why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using Zombies Instrument.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful, if you post your crashlog (without NSZombieEnabled). If it was an overreleased object, NSZombie would tell it. So probably its smth else.